# RoR - helper method that calls fields_for a variable number of times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fields-for

In my Rails app, I have a form which uses `fields_for` many times, sometimes nesting calls to `fields_for`.

Unfortunately, the graphic designer insists that the input fields be ordered in such a way that they are not grouped according to the model to which they pertain. Therefore, I would like to make a helper that would build the `fields_for` blocks easily for me, but I can't see how to get the helper method to nest a variable number of blocks.

To illustrate, I envision code looking something like the following:

```
<%= form_for @object do |f| %>
  <!-- The helper method should have a similar effect to the following... -->
  <%= f.fields_for :assoc_a do |assoc_a_builder| %>
    <%= assoc_a_builder.fields_for :assoc_b do |assoc_b_builder| %>
      <%= assoc_b_builder.text_field :field_name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>      
  <!-- ...when given the following data... -->
  <%= my_helper [f, :assoc_a, :assoc_b], :text_field, :field_name %>

<% end %>
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the following helper method (probably not the best thing around).

Example function call in view:

```
<%= form_for @object do |builder| %>
  <%= nested_form_field 'My label text', [builder, :association_name, :field_name], :collection_select, :my_model_id, MyModel.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

Function definition:

```
  # Outputs a label and input, nesting calls to fields_for if 'form' arg is an Array.
  # e.g. <%= nested_form_field nil, [builder, :approved_details], :collection_select, :my_model_id, MyModel.all, :id, :name %>
  # Make label_text nil for just the input tag, no wrapping elements.
  def nested_form_field label_text, form, helper_method, field, *args_for_helper_method
    if form.is_a? Array
      if form.length > 1
        form.shift.fields_for form.first do |builder|
          form[0] = builder
          nested_form_field label_text, form, helper_method, field, *args_for_helper_method
        end
      else
        nested_form_field label_text, form.first, helper_method, field, *args_for_helper_method
      end
    else
      if label_text.nil?
        form.send helper_method, field, *args_for_helper_method
      else
        %Q(<div class=row>
        <div class=span4>#{label_text}</div>
        #{ form.send helper_method, field, *args_for_helper_method }
        </div>).html_safe
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= simple_form_for(@primer3) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <% @primer3.attributes.each_pair do |name, value| %>
      <%= f.input name if value %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I realize that this gets the job done but requires way too much typing for my case, where I might nest something within two attribute sets, and only have that nest open for a single input, then have to do something totally different.

Comment: It's a quick & dirty method -- useful for prototyping but there is too much of a dependency with the column order for it to be used in many apps. It's an interesting technique though, as is your own approach. Cheers